# aria-describedby text not announced on <div> by JAWS

Tags: html, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have an HTML form with mainly 2 types of fields - text and checkboxes groups. Each form field has a hidden  that includes error message and connected to formfield with "aria-describedby".  When form with errors is hit submit button, common error message shows up on top and culprit fields gets error styling at field level.
As user tabs to errornous form to edit, to each field, field level error message  is also displayed via CSS changes. If JAWS is running, it is read out as user tabs into field.

But this is not happening for checkboxes group. I have checkboxes wrapper -  tabbable, user can Kb focus to it and error div is displayed but not announced.

We do not have aria-live and alert on each form field but on common error message div on top. This is on purpose as we want those errors to be announced first by JAWS as user hits save.

Any suggestions to this problem? I tried to have tabindex and aria-describedby /aria-invalid on outer div or on another wrapper div but failed to fix jaws issue.

```
<div style="display: none; left: -9999px; z-index: 1000; top: 335.717px;"              class="errorClass" id="showerror">Error: Please select a checkbox </div
<div>
<fieldset aria-describedby="showError"  aria-invalid="true"       id="myFieldSet" tabindex="0" >
<legend>some legend text</legend>
<div class="checkboxClass">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" name="chkgp">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" name="chkgp">
</div>
</fieldset>
</div></div>
```